# php uploading file

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I got EVERYTHING, but this working. I can't get the `move_uploaded_file();` to work.

```
$ups_path = "ups/files";
$nfile = $_FILES['nfile']['tmp_name'];
$cfile = move_uploaded_file($nfile, $ups_path);

if($cfile){
header ('Location: index.php?give=fileuploaded');
} else {
header ('Location: index.php?give=filenotuploaded');
}
```

It always returns the error for not moving it.

Comment: `$ups_path` should probably be absolute.

Comment: *What* error do you get? NB, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not useful at this point. It will not remove illegal characters in the file name.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string` on `tmp_name`? And probably you are changing the string. Check if this is the case.

Comment: That's what I did Majid. 'die(mysql_error());' isn't returning anything at all. I've tested on Firefox, Opera, and Chrome. Everything works flawless up to the point it has to move the file. All my folders are chmod 777 as well.

Comment: make sure the $ups_path exist and is writable

Comment: Sourav it is. I chmod 777 it and I also ran chmod -R 777 on all the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ups/files a directory then this will fail. move_uploaded_file expects the second argument to be a filename, not a directory.

Comment: Thank You! good catch. I forgot to make it like `$ups_path = "ups/files/$date_$filename";`. My script is working complete now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the absolute path instead of relative one:

```
$ups_path = "/var/www/somewhere/ups/files";
```